# How to make an asynchronous call to a function that doesn't return anything?

Tags: python, asynchronous

Suppose I define the following function:

```
import time

def slow() -> None:
    time.sleep(60)
```

How to make a call to `slow` asynchronously, such that the thread calling it never has to wait for it to finish before proceeding, for example:

```
def main():
    print("Hello")
    slow()
    print("World!") # Should not have to wait 60 seconds to execute this
```

Comment: You need a separate thread. The whole point of defining *asynchronous* functions is to hide the details of such thread management from the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are doing this, but you could make `slow` function async and don't add `await` to `slow()` in `main` function:

```py
import time

async def slow() -> None:
    time.sleep(60)

def main():
    print("Hello")
    slow()
    print("World!")
```

It will log some `RuntimeWarning`s but it will run successfully at the end.

```
Hello
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'slow' was never awaited
  slow()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
World!
```

---

I'd recommend you to create a thread running it to avoid those wranings:

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def slow() -> None:
    sleep(60)

def main():
    print("Hello")
    Thread(target=slow).start()
    print("World!")
```

If the `slow` function has been used more than once then you might give that thread a variable and just execute using `.start()` method.

Comment: In practice, `slow` will be a function that logs some usage information into a database. I don't want that process blocking the function that is being logged. What happens if the main function ends before the secondary thread?

Comment: It will wait until the thread is kill, the program won't be terminated until all threads are killed.

Comment: I'm not sure what the best approach is here, but I would use a regular logger; it wouldn't make much difference on the time needed to be logged.

Think about it differently: what if an error occurred in the logger function? The program will continue to work with errors thrown everywhere. And what if the logger function has been called to many time in short time? It will open many threads.

Comment: What do you mean by "errors thrown everywhere"? One of the reasons I like the ideia of an async/threaded logger is that I don't want errors in the logger spilling over the logged function.